# Finding movies that had an HD release and DVD Release on the same year

Tags: sql

So I have a table excerpt that looks like this:

```
Title         Type     Year   Rating
-------------------------
Interstellar  DVD   2014    8.4
Interstellar  HD    2014    8.4
12 Angry Men  DVD   1969    8.9
The Pianist   HD    2001    8.1
The Pianist   DVD   2001    8.1
Dragon Ball Z HD    2011    8.4
Dragon Ball Z DVD   1999    8.3
```

I want to retrieve all titles that have a DVD and HD released in the same year.
So, I would want to get Interstellar, The Pianist but not Dragon Ball Z since it's HD and DVD version were released on different years.

I managed to do it by joining tables but is it possible to do it without any joins?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `INTERSECT`:

```
SELECT Title, Year
FROM your_table
WHERE Type = 'DVD'
INTERSECT
SELECT Title, Year
FROM your_table
WHERE Type = 'HD';
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/377209)**</kbd>

If you need only title use subquery:

```
SELECT Title
FROM( SELECT Title, Year
      FROM your_table
      WHERE Type = 'DVD'
      INTERSECT
      SELECT Title, Year
      FROM your_table
      WHERE Type = 'HD') as t
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/377210)**</kbd>

One more possibility is to use `EXISTS` and correlated subquery:

```
SELECT Title
FROM your_table m1
WHERE Type = 'DVD'
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
             FROM your_table m2 
             WHERE m2.Title = m1.Title
               AND m2.Type = 'HD'
               AND m2.Year = m1.Year);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo3`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/377212)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, I like the intersection method the most. It answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Title, Year
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Title, Year
HAVING MIN(Type) <> MAX(Type)
```

Assuming there are only two available `Type` values, `'HD'` and `'DVD'`, the above query identifies `Title, Year` pairs that relate to both of these types.

If there are more types available then `HAVING` becomes a bit more complicated:

```
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'DVD' THEN 1 END) <> 0 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'HD' THEN 1 END) <> 0
```

Output:

```
Title           Year
-----------------------
The Pianist     2001
Interstellar    2014
```

Comment: This solution has one flaw, what if there is more types than 'DVD' and 'HD'?